# How to display an ip in normal character

Tags: python, special-characters, ip-address

I have a problem with my script. For a test i want to print an src and dst ip address but the characters displayed are special and after many researches i still don't understand why ... 
I'm sure this is a simply problem but i didnt get it ...

This is the output:

[image: problem]

And this is my script:

```
import pcapy
import dpkt
from threading import Thread
import re
import binascii

liste=[]
listip=[]
piece_request_handshake = re.compile('13426974546f7272656e742070726f746f636f6c(?P<reserved>\w{8})(?P<info_hash>\w{20})(?P<peer_id>\w{20})')
piece_request_tcpclose = re.compile('(?P<start>\w{12})5011')


class PieceRequestSniffer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, dev='eth0'):
        Thread.__init__(self)

        self.expr = 'udp or tcp'

        self.maxlen = 65535  # max size of packet to capture
        self.promiscuous = 1  # promiscuous mode?
        self.read_timeout = 100  # in milliseconds
        self.max_pkts = -1  # number of packets to capture; -1 => no limit

        self.active = True
        self.p = pcapy.open_live(dev, self.maxlen, self.promiscuous, self.read_timeout)
        self.p.setfilter(self.expr)

    @staticmethod
    def cb(hdr, data):

        eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(str(data))
        ip = eth.data

            #Select Ipv4 packets because of problem with the .p in Ipv6
        if eth.type == dpkt.ethernet.ETH_TYPE_IP6:
            return
        else:

            #Select only TCP protocols
            if ip.p == dpkt.ip.IP_PROTO_TCP:
                tcp = ip.data

                try:
                    #Return hexadecimal representation
                    hex_data = binascii.hexlify(tcp.data)
                except:
                    return

                fin_flag = ( tcp.flags & dpkt.tcp.TH_FIN ) != 0
                if fin_flag:
                    print " -------------------FIN filtered-------------------"
                    src_ip = ip.src
                    dst_ip = ip.dst
                    #listip.append(theip)
                    print "\n"
                    print "src_ip %s  %s dst_ip %s" % (src_ip,"\n", dst_ip)
                    #for element in zip(str(listip),str(thedata)):
                        #print(element)

    def stop(self):
        #logging.info('Piece Request Sniffer stopped...')
        self.active = False

    def run(self):
        while self.active:
            self.p.dispatch(0, PieceRequestSniffer.cb)


sniffer = PieceRequestSniffer()
sniffer.start()
```

Comment: `ip.src` and `ip.dst` are probably integers that you try to print as strings. You need a function that will convert an ip in integer form to a string representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, import `socket`, then use:

```
src_ip = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.src)
dst_ip = socket.inet_ntoa(ip.dst)
```